# Getting an error when trying to retrieve all files from Acumatica Sales Order through the API

Tags: acumatica

I'm successfully generating three files through the API.  The code I'm using to do that is here:

```
    public SalesOrder GenerateAcumaticaLabels(string orderNbr, string reportType)

    {

        SalesOrder salesOrder = null;

        using (ISoapClientProvider clientProvider = soapClientFactory.Create())

        {               

            try

            {

                SalesOrder salesOrderToFind = new SalesOrder

                {

                    OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = orderNbr.Split(OrderSeparator.SalesOrder).First() },

                    OrderNbr = new StringSearch { Value = orderNbr.Split(OrderSeparator.SalesOrder).Last() },

                    ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,

                };



                salesOrder = clientProvider.Client.Get(salesOrderToFind) as SalesOrder;                   



                InvokeResult invokeResult = new InvokeResult();

                switch (reportType)

                {

                    case "SFP":

                        invokeResult = clientProvider.Client.Invoke(salesOrder, new exportSFPReport());

                        break;

                    case "XFP":

                        invokeResult = clientProvider.Client.Invoke(salesOrder, new exportXFPReport());

                        break;   

                    case "Tray":

                        invokeResult = clientProvider.Client.Invoke(salesOrder, new exportTrayLabelReport());

                        break;

                    default:

                        throw new Exception("Report Type not recognized");                             

                }



                ProcessResult processResult = clientProvider.Client.GetProcessStatus(invokeResult);

                //Wait for the update to complete before we attempt to retrieve the files

                while (processResult.Status == ProcessStatus.InProcess)

                {

                    Thread.Sleep(1000); //pause for 1 second

                    processResult = clientProvider.Client.GetProcessStatus(invokeResult);

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {   

                IntegraLogging.LogError("Error generating sales order labels: " + ex.Message, EventID.Acumatica, ex, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, Departments.IT,

                    LocalEnvironment, "salesOrderNbr", salesOrder.OrderNbr.Value, null);

            }

        }

        return salesOrder;    

    }
```

I'm running into an error at .GetFiles when I try to retrieve the files I've generated:

```
 public Dictionary<string, Byte[]> RetrieveAcumaticaLabels(string orderNbr)

    {

        File[] files = null;

        SalesOrder salesOrder = null;

        Dictionary<string, Byte[]> filesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();



        using (ISoapClientProvider clientProvider = soapClientFactory.Create())

        {

            try

            {

                SalesOrder salesOrderToFind = new SalesOrder

                {

                    OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = orderNbr.Split(OrderSeparator.SalesOrder).First() },

                    OrderNbr = new StringSearch { Value = orderNbr.Split(OrderSeparator.SalesOrder).Last() },



                    ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,

                };



                salesOrder = clientProvider.Client.GetList(salesOrderToFind).Cast<SalesOrder>().FirstOrDefault();       

                //Get the files and put the content into a dictionary by name                    

                files = clientProvider.Client.GetFiles(salesOrder) as IntegraDataServices.AcumaticaOpticsExt.File[];



                foreach (File file in files)

                {

                    //Store the filename as just the filename, location info excluded, so we don't have to rebuild it later to retrieve it.

                    string[] fileName = file.Name.Split(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

                    //Only store the file once, in case of dupes

                    if (!filesDictionary.ContainsKey(fileName[2]))

                    {

                        filesDictionary.Add(fileName[2], file.Content);

                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                IntegraLogging.LogError("Error retrieving sales order labels: " + ex.Message, EventID.Acumatica, ex, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, Departments.IT,

                    LocalEnvironment, "salesOrderNbr", orderNbr, null);

            }

        }

        return filesDictionary;    

    }
```

Here is the error I'm encountering:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element

   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.Post(ISoapSystemContract systemContract, XmlReader requestReader, String serviceNamespace, String internalNamespace, MethodInfo method, Func`1 serviceFactory, IEdmModel edmModel)

   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Post>d__8.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Login>d__6.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I was able to generate and retrieve files from the Kit Assembly successfully; I'm not certain what's causing the problem doing it from Sales Orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working here was removing the GetList call before the GetFiles.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following example and it worked in my environment. This might require troubleshooting.

Try removing and adding back the service reference, try multiple sales order, restart the application (IISReset).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WebServiceTest.ServiceReference1;

namespace WebServiceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (DefaultSoapClient soapClient = new DefaultSoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None)
            {
                AllowCookies = true,
                Name = "DefaultSoap",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            },
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/089253/entity/Default/17.200.001?wsdl")))
            {
                try
                {
                    soapClient.Login("admin", "admin", "USA", null, null);

                    SalesOrder salesOrderToFind = new SalesOrder
                    {
                        OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = "SO" },
                        OrderNbr = new StringSearch { Value = "SO004519" },
                        ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,
                    };

                    SalesOrder salesOrder = soapClient.GetList(salesOrderToFind).Cast<SalesOrder>().FirstOrDefault();
                    File[] file = soapClient.GetFiles(salesOrder) as File[];
                    soapClient.Logout();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try { soapClient.Logout(); } catch { }
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We just did a merge that affected our webservice endpoint, so I'm going to see if that's the source of the problem as well.  Thank you for the pointers, I'll keep you posted!

Comment: Could be, in Visual Studio remove (don't update) the service reference and add back the new one using the new wsdl URL.